# Create New Entity With New Retaled Entities in 1 Transaction

Tags: relationship, microsoft-dynamics

We are dynamics api to create entities as below:
Guid id = _orgService.Create(entity);

How can I create entity with related entities, if related entities are also new?

Should I create all entities seperately and call 
_orgService.Associate(entity.LogicalName, entity.Id, relationship, relatedEntities); ??

Or can I do it with 1 transaction?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into creating the related entities via Plugin? You could make one create call to the parent entity and have the plugin that executes create the child or related entities.

If that's not feasible then I think you'll need multiple service calls. You cant add the related entity reference if the related entity doesn't already exist. You'll have an exception returned.

If you go the service call route then the least number of calls you can make is 2. One to create the initial entity, and a second to create the related entity with the relationship populated.